# Chrome extension: Getting html of page before page renders/loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

Context: I'm making a program that extracts the main content from a webpage. However, currently what I am doing is waiting for the entire webpage to load and render (which can take a long time, especially for pages with a lot of scripts).

What I want is to just get the html of the page right when the page starts loading so I can extract the main content without having to wait for the entire webpage to render and load.

```
run_at: "document_start"
```

in the mainfest.json file does not work because it is run before the html even appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `run_at: "document_start"` with [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event listener (or [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) if you want to process the document *while* it's loading) in your content script.

Comment: "The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document **has been completely loaded and parsed**" [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).  If you're waiting for `DOMConentLoaded` event, then there is no difference with `document_end`. I'm voting down this, because this does not solve the problem that `do xxx right when the page starts loading`.

Comment: @VicX, the difference is that it takes time for content scripts to be injected. Chrome does a lot of intermediate things when it creates runtime environment. The chromium developers recognize the problem and are working on optimization, e.g. js bindings are being rewritten in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `"document_end"`, it should run earlier than the default `"document_idle"`.

Comment: however, document_end can also take much longer than needed, specially if the page has iframes (lots do for doing google auth for example, and regardless of injecting in iframes). i recently swtiched my extension to document_start with great sucess but had to fix some libraries that expected the dom be there during script load (instead moved that init later). if html isnt there yet just wait for it with timeouts/interval